# Using CompletableFuture to build an object with multiple methods

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand `CompletableFuture` and how I can utilise it to build an object with information obtained from several endpoints. I've come across a few examples but none are quite tailored to my problem. For example, [this one](https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0) is running the same method in parallel to get a list of strings where I want to run multiple methods in parallel to build and return an object.

I've created a simple DTO for an employee:

```java
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeDTO {

    private String name;
    private String accountNumber;
    private int salary;

}
```

I've created a service to mimic calls to three separate APIs to set the values of the DTO with a considerable wait time:

```java
public class EmployeeService {

    public EmployeeDTO setName() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return EmployeeDTO.builder().name("John Doe").build();
    }

    public EmployeeDTO setAccountNumber() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return EmployeeDTO.builder().accountNumber("1235").build();
    }

    public EmployeeDTO setSalary() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return EmployeeDTO.builder().salary(100000).build();
    }
}
```

I can `supplyAsync` all three of the methods and then run `allOf` but it doesn't do anything:

```java
    private void run() {
        EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();

        CompletableFuture<EmployeeDTO> employeeCfWithName = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(employeeService::setName);
        CompletableFuture<EmployeeDTO> employeeCfWithAccountNumber = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(employeeService::setAccountNumber);
        CompletableFuture<EmployeeDTO> employeeCfWithSalary = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(employeeService::setSalary);

        CompletableFuture allCompletableFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(employeeCfWithName, employeeCfWithAccountNumber, employeeCfWithSalary);
    }
```

How can I combine the results into one EmployeeDTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to combine the results of the three `CompletableFuture`s into a single `EmployeeDTO`. This is not magically done by `allOf`.

Try something like this (untested):

```java
CompletableFuture allCompletableFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(
  employeeCfWithName, employeeCfWithAccountNumber, employeeCfWithSalary);

// Wait for all three to complete.
allCompletableFutures.get();

// Now join all three and combine the results.
EmployeeDTO finalResult = EmployeeDTO.builder()
  .name(new employeeCfWithName.join())
  .accountNumber(new employeeCfWithAccountNumber.join())
  .salary(new employeeCfWithSalary.join())
  .build();
```

This looks a little bit silly. We use a builder in every method just to combine their results using a fourth builder.

Comment: I agree with your point about the excessive builder usage being silly. In order to address this I made the `EmployeeService` methods return a type related to the method (e.g. String for name) and I only had to build once. Cautionary note: the code given above is, as stated, untested and will require some changes but the gist is there.

Answer (score 0):

Make you employee service functions take **EmployeeDTO.builder()** as input and then in run() function create one builder and pass that builder in the all supplyAsync calls to service. Also make sure that you build() after allOf() call which guarantees that every service call is done with its part. Also do not build in individual service function -

```
public class EmployeeService {

    public EmployeeDTO setName(EmployeeDTO.EmployeeDTOBuilder builder) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.name("John Doe");
    }

    public EmployeeDTO setAccountNumber(EmployeeDTO.EmployeeDTOBuilder builder) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.accountNumber("1235");
    }

    public EmployeeDTO setSalary(EmployeeDTO.EmployeeDTOBuilder builder) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return builder.salary(100000);
    }
}
```

```
private void run() {
        EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();

        EmployeeDTO.EmployeeDTOBuilder builder = EmployeeDTO.builder();

        CompletableFuture<EmployeeDTO> employeeCfWithName = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(()-> emoplyeeService.setName(builder));
        CompletableFuture<EmployeeDTO> employeeCfWithAccountNumber = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(()-> emoplyeeService.setAccount(builder));
        CompletableFuture<EmployeeDTO> employeeCfWithSalary = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(()-> emoplyeeService.setSalary(builder));

        CompletableFuture allCompletableFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(employeeCfWithName, employeeCfWithAccountNumber, employeeCfWithSalary);

        builder.build();
    }
```

Comment: You don't wait for `allCompletableFutures` to finish.

Comment: yes, in that case you can handle it asynchronously using something like thenAccept() or thenRun() whatever